# Jackson Serialization: Unwrap collection elements using

Tags: java, json, serialization, jackson

Is there a way to serialize collection and its elements unwrapped?

For example I want to serialize unwrapped all `components`:

```
class Model {

  @JsonProperty
  @JsonUnwrapped
  Collection<Object> components;

  Model(Collection<Object> components) {
    this.components = components;
  }

  static class Component1 {
    @JsonProperty
    String stringValue;

    Component1(String stringValue) {
      this.stringValue= stringValue;
    }
  }

  static class Component2 {
    @JsonProperty
    int intValue;

    Component2(int intValue) {
      this.intValue= intValue;
    }
  }

  public static void main(String[] args) throws JsonProcessingException {
    Model model = new Model(Arrays.asList(new Component1("something"), new Component2(42)));
    String json = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(model);
    System.out.println(json);
  }
}
```

Expected:

> {"stringValue":"something","intValue":42}

But actual result is:

> {"components":[{"stringValue":"something"},{"intValue":42}]}

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Custom serializer might help:

```
  class ModelSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Model> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Model model, JsonGenerator generator, SerializerProvider serializers) throws IOException {
      generator.writeStartObject();

      JsonSerializer<Object> componentSerializer = serializers.findValueSerializer(getClass());
      JsonSerializer<Object> unwrappingSerializer = componentSerializer.unwrappingSerializer(NameTransformer.NOP);
      unwrappingSerializer.serialize(this, generator, serializers);

      generator.writeEndObject();
    }
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't see a way to do that without custom serialization. I recommend these 2 serializers:

```
class ValueSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Object value, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sers) throws IOException {
        for (Field field : value.getClass().getDeclaredFields()) {
            try {
                field.setAccessible(true);
                gen.writeObjectField(field.getName(), field.get(value));
            } catch (IllegalAccessException ignored) {
            }
        }
    }
}

class ModelSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Model> {
    @Override
    public void serialize(Model model, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider sers) throws IOException {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        for (Object obj : model.getComponents()) {
            gen.writeObject(obj);
        }
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Notice how we don't call `writeStartObject()` at `ValueSerializer` so no extra curly braces from here, neither from `writeObjectField`. On the other hand in `ModelSerializer` `writheStartObject` adds curly braces, and then we dump within them each object in `components`

You'd also need to annotate serializable classes to use these serializers e.g.

```
@JsonSerialize(using = ValueSerializer.class)
class Component1 {

@JsonSerialize(using = ValueSerializer.class)
class Component2 {

@JsonSerialize(using = ModelSerializer.class)
class Model {
```

Answer (score 0):

Not elegant, but work code.
Sure about unique naming of key values

```
 @JsonProperty
@JsonSerialize(using = CollectionSerializer.class)
Collection<Object> components;

static class CollectionSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Object> {

    @Override
    public void serialize(Object o, JsonGenerator jsonGenerator, SerializerProvider serializerProvider) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        jsonGenerator.writeStartObject();
        if (o instanceof Collection) {
            Collection c = (Collection) o;
            for (Object el : c) {
                if (el instanceof Component1) {
                    jsonGenerator.writeStringField("stringValue", ((Component1) el).stringValue);
                }
                if (el instanceof Component2) {
                    jsonGenerator.writeNumberField("intValue", ((Component2) el).intValue);
                }
            }
        }
        jsonGenerator.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```